# Vue.js - Why cant i insert to the html table?

Tags: vuejs2

I am currently working on a table where I want to show data of a robot. The li works fine, but the table will not show the data. I am using vue.js 2 btw. Does anyone know where my mistake is?

````html
<template>
    <div class="stats">
        Statistiken
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
                    {{maschine.maschineId}}
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableData">
            <tr>
                <td v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId ">
                    {{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.datum}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <li v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
            {{maschine.maschineId}}
            <ul v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId">
        
                <div id="before"
                     v-if="feed.datum >= '2020-10-03' + ' 00:00:00' && feed.datum <= '2020-10-03' + '23:59:59'"
                     style="margin-left: 300px; color: red">
                    {{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.datum}}
                </div>
                <!--<div id="after" v-else>
                    {{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.timestamp}}
                </div>-->
            </ul>
        </li>
    </div>
</template> ```
````

Comment: fyi, `<li>` element must be contained in a parent element, `<ol>`, `<ul>` or `<menu>`

Comment: Anything in the browser console, any errors? `:key="feed.feedsId "` remove that space maybe. Do you know of the VueDevTools browser addon?

Comment: Try replacing `<li>` and `<ul>` with `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the **v-for** in the **tbody** is incorrect. The variable **maschine** here is **undefined**.
The first **v-for** in the **thead** is already done. That's why the variable **maschine** in the second **v-for** is **undefined**.

To make it work, replace your tbody with the following

```html
<tbody id="tableData">
    <tr>
        <td v-for="maschine in userdaten.maschinen" :key="maschine.maschineId">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="feed in maschine.feeds" :key="feed.feedsId ">{{feed.feedsId}} - {{feed.datum}}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If it doesn't give you the desired format, show me the userdaten structure and I can help you.